# how to move heap area data to String constant pool?

Tags: java, constants, heap-memory, string-pool

how to move heap area data to String constant pool ?

```
        String s3 = new String("Test");
         final String s4 = s3.intern();
         System.out.println(s3 == s4);//fasle(i need true)
```

i dont want to create new object so just cut the object from heap and paste it in String constant pool

Comment: `System.out.println(s3.equals(s4))`.  In other words, don't compare references, compare the data.  I don't see that there's _ever_ a need to compare `String` references (other than to `null`), and if you think you have a need for it, you have probably designed your program wrong.  To answer your question, `s3.intern()` creates a new object and thus the references will _never_ be equal.

Comment: i dont want to create new object so just cut the object from heap and paste it in String constant pool .

Comment: Almost everything in Java is an object.  Java is not Microsoft Word, and you can't just "cut and paste" data without creating a new object.  You really need to go back and study the fundamentals of Java.

Answer (score 0):

You are not moving heap data to the String constants pool when you call `intern`, you are just adding another new String to the constants pool if it doesn't already exist in the constants pool (which doesn't happen in your case as `"Test"` is already added to constants pool in line -1).

You might want to change your code to :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s3 = new String("Test");
    s3 = s3.intern();
    String s4 = "Test";
    System.out.println(s3 == s4);//fasle(i need true)
}
```

In the above code you assign the reference to the interned value of s3 to s3 again. Next,you get the same object from String constants pool in S4.

Comment: i want move(cut) the heap area data to String constant pool?but when am using intern just it copy the object..

Comment: i dont want to create new object so just cut the object from heap and paste it in String constant pool

Comment: @ShivarajMc - Well, once the GC runs, the String `Test` which is on heap will be eligible for GC. Thus you are indirectly doing a cut-paste of the same object with some delay

Comment: @ShivarajMc - You can't "move" an object from one place to another (JIT can do it if it wants to though).

Comment: your correct.... ("Test" is already added to constants pool in line -1)